# Proper Orderby for query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Given the following:

```
Create Table Person
(
     ID         int ,
     Lastname   varchar(32),
     Firstname  varchar(32)
);

Create Table Families
(
     ID int,
     PersonId_fk int,
     IsHeadOfHousehold bit
);

Insert into Person Values(1, 'Smith', 'John');
Insert into Person Values(4, 'Johnson', 'Sue');
Insert into Person Values(2, 'Smith', 'Jane');
Insert into Person Values(3, 'Towmater', 'Billy');

Insert into Families Values(1, 1, 1);
Insert into Families Values(1, 2, 0);
Insert into Families Values(1, 3, 0);
Insert into Families Values(1, 4, 0);
```

I am having trouble getting the results to appear in the following order. What I am trying to do, is get the head of the household to appear first, followed by anyone with the same last name, and finally everyone else ordered by last name

```
Smith     John      1
Smith     Jane      0
Johnson   Sue       0
Towmater  Billy     0
```

I've tried this

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, IsHeadOfHousehold
FROM families f
join person p
on f.PersonID_fk = p.ID
where f.Id = 1
Order by IsHeadOfHousehold DESC, LastName, FirstName
```

which gets me close, but doesn't get me what i want.

Comment: Why the `where f.id = 1`?

Comment: eric : because that is the family I want the list of people for. in practice there are many different families in this table

Comment: What's the output u getting? what order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server, if you are using 2005+, you should be able to use `row_number()` to order the data:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, IsHeadOfHousehold
FROM families f
join person p
  on f.PersonID_fk = p.ID
where f.Id = 1
order by IsHeadOfHousehold desc, 
  row_number() over(partition by lastname order by IsHeadOfHousehold desc) desc, 
  lastname, firstname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ced4e/9)